# the use of `%3F` in URL

Tags: html, url

While moving a website - that I did not build - I have run into the use of `%3F`.

`%3F` is the [percent-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) version of `?`.

It seems to be used like this a lot:

```
<ahref="example%3Flang=1.html">Example</a>
```

when linking to a file named `example_lang=1.html`.

So, I replaced `%3F` with `_`, and all works again.

I am missing something here. The old website worked. After being moved, it no longer worked. After the replacement of `%3F` to `_`, the links worked again. Why?

Comment: In your example you replaced `%3F` with `_` but the true decoded character of `%3F` is `?` as you also point out. Can you please provide another example so we can see the problem? From the example it seems that also before it didn't work as expected.

Comment: What I am working with is a number of files downloaded from a website. On second look on that website it seems it generates the .html from a database... Gonne talk this over with my colleague who thought this up. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, you should elaborate your question to understand it better after all If I understood it correctly then this might be the answer.

"_" is not a reserved URI character.

As you said that %3F is reserved for "?" then you are absolutely right but if you read the documentation written on wiki states that "_"(underscore) is not a reserved URI character.

So that for example if the URL for a web page is "**example_test.html**" then its encoded URL must be "**example_test.html**" if there is not any mechanism applied on that URL. Now I will take an another example of PHP based web page that may answer your question.

In PHP there is a function "**str_replace**" that is used to replace the string by programmer defined characters or string.

Let assume that I have a page named "**example_test.html**" and for some xyz reasons I want to change it to "**example%3Ftest.html**" then I can use

`str_replace("%3F","_","<a href='example%3Ftest.html'>Example Test</a>");`

This function will search for all occurences of "**%3F**" and replace it with "**_**" in provided string(here "**href=example%3Ftest.html**") and output as "**href='example_test.html**" which is the actual link for my file.